# `Div.backgroundColor` change to `Element.backgroundColor` using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change `#Content.backgroundColor` to `elem.backgroundColor` using JavaScript.

Here is HTML codes :

```
<button class="red"   onClick="changeColor(this);">Btn1</button>
<button class="blue"  onClick="changeColor(this);">Btn2</button>
<button class="green" onClick="changeColor(this);">Btn3</button>
<div id="Content"></div>
```

And here is CSS code :

```
.red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.blue {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.green {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
#Content {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

JS codes is here : **(My problem is here)**

```
function changeColor(elem){
document.getElementById("Content").style.backgroundColor = elem.style.backgroundColor;    
}
```

[DEMO in JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QZcSF/)

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `style` property maps onto the `style` attribute, not the value of the CSS property as calculated by running through the cascade.

You need to examine [the computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle).