# Change Element.attr when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is pretty like [my last topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298413/div-backgroundcolor-change-to-element-backgroundcolor-using-javascript), but it's not the same.

---

I have several buttons and styled by CSS.

HTML codes is here :

```
<button class="Btn red">Btn1</button>
<button class="Btn blue">Btn2</button>
<button class="Btn green">Btn3</button>
<div id="Content"></div>
```

And CSS codes is here :

```
.red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.blue {
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
.green {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
#Content {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

My question is :

How do i change `(#Content).backgroundcolor`  to `(Clicked_Btn).backgroundcolor` using Javascript.

I have tried below JS commands, i think it has a lot of problems :

```
$(".Btn").click(function(){
document.getElementById("Content").style.backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(this).backgroundColor;    
);
```

[DEMO in JsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4nYsH/)

---

P.S :

As i mentioned above please don't suggest something like :

```
// HTML 

<button class="Btn red" onClick="changeColor(this);">Btn1</button>
...

//JavaScript

function changeColor(elem){
document.getElementById("Content").style.backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(elem).backgroundColor;    
}
```

I don't want to use `onClick("function();")` inside HTML button tags.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure Javascript (no jQuery dependency):

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("Content").style.backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(this).backgroundColor;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YE3mj/4/)

Answer (score 3):

if you are using $(".Btn").click then you are using jquery. This means that you can simplify a lot the subsequent line.

```
$(".Btn").click(function(){
  $("#Content").css('background-color',$(this).css('background-color'));   
});
```

and here is your fiddle edited: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AFBTp/)